Launchscreen on Android on my flutter project keeps using images from mipmap instead of drawable
The image for my android launch screen keeps getting drawn from the mipmap folders rather than the drawable folder.
I have modififed the launch background xml files in both drawable and drawable v-21 folders and still nothing. Anyone got any ideas?
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>


well, in Android, you cannot custom your splash screen like iOS - except you create 2 splash screens! The initial splash screen will always be your app's icon
